# Crank Sugino Impel peeled off

Tags: crankset, chrome

I have Sugino Impel Crank that little bit peeled off (like white spot and Gray Spot).
Can I fix this issue with wet sanding using sand paper?
I already search little bit, but still Im not sure it will work.
Anyone have experience in polishing crank?
Thanks before.

here attached image for reference

[image: Image_Reference]

Comment: I'd leave it. It's harmless.

Comment: Looks like a layer of electroplated chrome?  You'll not fix that easily, a small pottle of nail polish in a chrome-like colour might be your best option.

Comment: The result of poor preparatory fork at the factory. Depending on the age of the piece you could just complain to the seller.

Comment: @Criggie I'd suspect that's peeling clear coat rather than chrome. Chrome plating is no longer very common on bikes and parts; also, I don't know if it adheres to aluminum components.

Comment: @WeiwenNg correct - Chrome is a process for steel.  Anodising is the equivalent for aluminium, but it does not flake.

Comment: @Criggie anodizing is accompanied by a clear coat. That can flake. And the photo does look like flaking clear coat to my eye. That’s what I was trying to convey.

Answer (score 3):

I had that on a Campagnolo C-Record crank.  The satin-anodized finish was worn where the previous owner's shoe rubbed it.  As far as I know the only real solution is to remove the entire anodized layer and expose the aluminum underneath, which can be polished to a nice shine.  A post on another site recommended using oven cleaner to loosen it.  I had little luck with that, but used a lot of elbow grease and a Dremel wire brush.  The disadvantage is that I had to remove the Campagnolo logo, too.
[image: Here are before and after pictures]